# Recently Posted Question Limited Visibility

Tags: support, specific-question

Earlier today, I posted following [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/242530/decoupling-implies-local-decoupling). Shortly later, I noticed that it was no longer visible when one looks at the "Newest" list for the tags fourier-analysis and harmonic-analysis, both of which were used for the question. However, I still can see the question when I search for it. I do not see any indication of moderator activity--if I am able to see such things--so I am wondering why this has occurred.

Comment: And now it appears to be fully visible--both on the main page and the aforementioned tag lists. Strange...

Comment: Strange indeed. I saw exactly what you saw.

Comment: For how long was your question not visible on the "newest" list? -- According to my observations, it seems that a question often appears there only once 5 minutes or so have passed (the time during which one can make changes without producing a new revision).

Comment: @StefanKohl At least an 45 minutes to 1 hour.